# Why does $\frac{d}{dx}\delta(x-a)=-\frac{d}{da}\delta(x-a)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, dirac-delta

I am reading Shankars principles of Quantum Mechanics and in his discussion of the derivative of the delta function, he simply writes that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\delta(x-a)=-\frac{d}{da}\delta(x-a)$$
I can't seem to figure out how we get the RHS from the LHS?
Any help on this issue would be most appreciated!

```
                                     **EDIT**
```

I am aware that we need to apply the chain rule to solve this as follows: Let $u=x-a$, then
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d}{da}\delta(x-a) &=& \frac{d}{du}\delta(u)|_{u=x-a} \frac{du}{da} \\
\Rightarrow &=&\frac{d}{du}\delta(u)|_{u=x-a} \frac{d}{da}(x-a) \\
\Rightarrow &=& -\frac{d}{du}\delta(u)|_{u=x-a}
\end{eqnarray}
The derivative in the last line is with respect to $u$ not $x$. In order to evaluate this derivative, we must derive $δ(u)$ with respect to $u$ and *then* evaluate the result at $u=x−a$. But how do we know that this is equal to simply deriving $\delta(x-a)$ with respect to $x$? For an arbitrary function $f(x)$, we have that in general $\frac{df(g(x))}{dx}\neq \frac{df(x)}{dx}|_{x=g(x)}$. So why do we infer in the case of the delta function that $\frac{d\delta(x-a)}{dx}=\frac{d\delta(u)}{du}|_{u=x-a}$ ?

Comment: Write the functions differently. Set $f(x):=\delta(x-y)$ and $g(y):=\delta(x-y).$ Then differentiate $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ in terms of $\delta'$ and don't forget the chain rule.

Comment: @MariusS.L. Thanks for the response. Setting $f(x)=\delta(x-a)$ and $g(a)=\delta(x-a)$ and deriving I get that $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\delta(x-a)$ and $\frac{d}{dx}g(a)=\frac{dg}{da}\frac{da}{dx}$. I am not sure how to proceed further as I do not know what $\frac{da}{dx}$ is

Comment: It isn't $\dfrac{da}{dx},$ it is $\dfrac{d}{dx} (x-a)=-1$.

Comment: Surely $\dfrac{d}{dx} (x-a)=1$ not $-1$, since $\frac{d}{dx}x = 1$ and $a$ is a constant?

Comment: Yes. And the roles of $x$ and $a$ switch in the second term. If you have $\dfrac{d f(z)}{d z}=\dfrac{d}{d z}f(z)$ then $f$ is the function and $z$ in the denominator tells you what the variable is. $f$ may or may not depend on $z,$ or on more variables than $z$ in which case we write $\partial $ instead of $d.$

Comment: Im confused though. If $\dfrac{d}{dx} (x-a)=1$, not $-1$, then where does the minus in the equation in the question title come from?

Comment: Okay Thanks for the help. I've got the solution. I simply applied the chain rule formula strictly as follows: let $u=x-a$. Then $\frac{d}{da}\delta(x-a)=\frac{d}{du}\delta(u)|_{u=x-a}\frac{du}{da}$ but now $dx=du$ so we get the final result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f$ be a differentiable function. Then, by [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Statement) we have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x-y)
= f'(x-y) \cdot \frac{\partial (x-y)}{\partial x}
= f'(x-y) \cdot 1
= f'(x-y)
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x-y)
= f'(x-y) \cdot \frac{\partial (x-y)}{\partial y}
= f'(x-y) \cdot (-1)
= -f'(x-y).
$$
Thus,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x-y)
= -\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x-y).
$$

This generalizes to distributions like $\delta$ by taking limits of [nascent $\delta$ functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#nascent_delta_function).

Comment: Aha! Okay, crystal clear now. Thanks a lot for the help! People like you make this site such a brilliant learning resource!

Answer (score 2):

These are actually partial derivatives.

If we let $u=x-t$, that is, $u$ is a function of $x$ and $t$, then we get $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=1$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-1$. Therefore, the chain rule says
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x-t)=\frac{\partial f\circ u}{\partial x}\!\!\!\!\stackrel{\large\overset{\text{chain rule}}{\downarrow\\\phantom{}}}=\!\!\!\!(f'\circ u)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=f'\circ u=f'(x-t)
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x-t)=\frac{\partial f\circ u}{\partial t}\!\!\!\!\stackrel{\large\overset{\text{chain rule}}{\downarrow\\\phantom{}}}=\!\!\!\!(f'\circ u)\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-f'\circ u=-f'(x-t)
$$
Thus,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x-t)=-f'(x-t)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x-t)
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d}{da}\delta(x-a) = \frac{d}{dx}\delta(x-a)\frac{d}{da}(x-a)
= \frac{d}{dx}\delta(x-a)\cdot(-1)=-\frac{d}{dx}\delta(x-a)$$

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am not sure how you get from $\frac{d}{da}\delta(x-a)$ to $ \frac{d}{dx}\delta(x-a)\frac{d}{da}(x-a)$ though

Comment: @SalahTheGoat. Chain rule.

Comment: @md2perpe Thanks. My issue is that when I apply the chain rule, I do as follows: Let $u=x-a$, then $\frac{d}{da}\delta(x-a) = \frac{d}{du}\delta(u)|_{u=x-a} \frac{du}{da}= \frac{d}{du}\delta(u)|_{u=x-a} \frac{d}{da}(x-a) =-\frac{d}{du}\delta(u)|_{u=x-a}$ . The last derivative is with respect to $u$ not x. In order to evaluate this derivative, we must derive $\delta (u)$ with respect to $u$ and *then* evaluate the result at $u=x-a$. This is in general not the same as taking $\delta$ first evaluated at $x-a$ and then deriving with respect to $x$. Yet the above answer derives $\delta(x-a)$ with x

Comment: @md2perpe I guess what I'm saying is that in general $\frac{df(g(x))}{dx}\neq \frac{df(x)}{dx}|_{x=g(x)}$. In the above answer, the poster suggests that we calculate the first option   ($\frac{d\delta(x-a)}{dx}$) but the chain rule says we should apply the second option ($\frac{d\delta(u)}{du}|_{u=x-a}$). Are these simply equal in the case of the delta function or is this a notational issue? That is, for the delta function, does $\frac{d\delta(x-a)}{dx}=\frac{d\delta(u)}{du}|_{u=x-a}$? Because for a general function, this equality does not hold.

Comment: @SalahTheGoat. Yes, in general $\frac{df(g(x))}{dx}\neq \frac{df(x)}{dx}|_{x=g(x)}$ but quite generally one has $\frac{df(g(x))}{dx}\neq \frac{df(x)}{dx}|_{x=g(x)} g'(x).$ Here, $g'(x)=1.$

Comment: @md2perpe Thanks, do you mean equality in your second equation?

Comment: @md2perpe Assuming you did mean equality, we then get that $\frac{d \delta (u)}{du}|_{u=x-a}=\frac{d\delta(x-a)}{du}\frac{d(x-a)}{du}=\frac{d\delta(x-a)}{du}\cdot 1$ where the derivative is still with respect to $u$ not the desired $x$. To fix this, do we simply note that $u=x-a \Rightarrow du=dx$ and then replace the denominator in $\frac{d\delta(x-a)}{du}$ by $dx$? This seems very lacking in rigor to me?

Comment: @SalahTheGoat. Yes, I meant equality. It was a copy-and-paste error.

Comment: @SalahTheGoat. If $f$ is just a differentiable function instead of a distribution like $\delta,$ do you also in that case doubt the analogous identity?
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x-y) = f'(x-y) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x-y)$$

Comment: @md2perpe Honestly, only somewhat. By strict application of the chain rule: Let $u=x-y$ so that $\frac{d}{dx}f(x-y)=\frac{d f(u)}{du}|_{u=x-y}\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{d f(u)}{du}|_{u=x-y} \cdot 1=\frac{d f}{du}(x-y)$. The derivative is still with respect to $u$. In order to change it to $y$, do we simply note that $u=x-y \rightarrow du=-dy$ and thus simply make the replacement $\frac{d}{du}=-\frac{d}{dy}$. If this is valid, then yes I understand but still think the argument lacks rigor. If its not valid then I do not understand. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @SalahTheGoat. I added an answer instead of continuing here. We can continue discussions there if you still don't get it.